# Problema con PHP y SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(3): include_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion.php on line 7

Código:

```html
<?php
// datos para la conexion a mysql
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','*****');
define('DB_USER','*****');
define('DB_PASS','*****');
$con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con);
?>
```

Comment: Hola Sergio, esta misma pregunta se ha realizado ya antes. Busca en el sitio porque encontrarás la solución que buscas (el código puede ser algo diferente, pero la causa es la misma). Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: Perdón no me fijé. ¿Elimino la pregunta?

Comment: No hace falta que la elimines. Que sea un duplicado no es malo en sí, solo significa que varias personas tienen el mismo problema. Al cerrarla como duplicado, se enlazan las preguntas similares para que sea más fácil para otros usuarios encontrar respuestas.

Comment: Ah perfecto, gracias!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Qué versión de PHP usas? El driver mysql_connect() está obsoleto desde PHP 5.5.0 y eliminado desde PHP 7.0.0 Deberías usar el driver mysqli_connect.

http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:database:mysql

Comment: Si, pero el nivel E_DEPRECATED no lanza un Fatal error, el Fatal error lo lanza porque estará utilizando la versión 7.0.0 o mayor de PHP, lo que supone que esta eliminado  no obsoleto, de ahí mi corrección. Un saludo.

Comment: Voy a borrar los comentarios, @Huskie no para de editar sus comentarios haciendo que la conversación haya perdido todo el sentido que tenía.

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar cada instrucción que tengas en php de mysql por mysqli. Esto debido a que las instrucciones tipo "mysql" están obsoletas desde PHP 5.5 y eliminadas desde PHP 7.0

Dejo tú código con las correcciones para que funcione:

```
<?php
// datos para la conexion a mysql
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','*****');
define('DB_USER','*****');
define('DB_PASS','*****');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

?>
```

Para conocer más sobre el tema te recomiendo revisar [características obsoletas PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/es/migration55.deprecated.php) y para observar con más detalle como se realiza una conexión con mysqli a manera de ejemplo puedes chequear [mysqli_connect](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: Me salta un nuevo error al usar ese código.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion.php on line 8